# How to access array in array?

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, server

how can i access posts data, like [message] and [created_time] from Facebook Graph Api?

Here is the print_r of JSON , which I'm getting from Facebook Graph Api

```
Array 
( 
[posts] => Array 
    ( 
        [data] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => Array 
            ( 
            [message] => random message. 
            [created_time] => 2016-11-12T07:26:23+0000 
            [id] => id786456786
            )                                                   
            [1] => Array 
            ( 
            [message] => random message. 
            [created_time] => 2016-11-11T04:30:02+0000 
            [id] => id123456768
            ) 
        ) 
        [paging] => Array 
        ( 
        [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/pageid/posts?limit=2&since=1478935583&access_token=MY ACCESS TOKEN ....        
        ) 
    ) 
    [id] => id
)
```

My php code:

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8facebookpageid?fields=posts.limit(2)&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN");

$decoded = json_decode($data,true);

print_r($decoded);
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `$array['key']['subkey']['subsubkey']` etc

Comment: `$decoded['posts']['data'][0]['message']`

Comment: Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply follow the array's key:

```
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);

// Retrieve the first message.
$message = $decoded['posts']['data'][0]['message']

// Retrieve the second message.
$message = $decoded['posts']['data'][1]['message']
```

Even better, you can loop through the `$decoded['posts']['data']` like so:

```
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($decoded['posts']['data'] as $item) {
    echo "Message: {$item['message']}\n";
    echo "Created Time: {$item['created_time']}\n";
}
```

Read more about [PHP Array here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the help!